# Managed C++ dll function throws access violation on return when called from Visual Studio process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, access-violation, managed-c++

I have a managed C++ dll which is used as a [EEAddIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for Visual Studio debugger. My dll exports one function accepting and returning unmanaged types. The declaration of the function in the dll is as follows (DEBUGHELPER is a plain structure):

```
extern "C" 
{
#pragma unmanaged
  __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CvMatViewer(DWORD dwAddress, DEBUGHELPER *pHelper, 
    int nBase, BOOL bUniStrings, char *pResult, size_t max, DWORD reserved)
  {
    strcpy_s(pResult, max, "Value is processed");
    return S_OK;
  }
}
```

The purpose of my dll is to handle variables from Visual Studio debugger and to format them in arbitrary way prior to displaying in Watch Window (that what EEAddIn is for, pretty cool).

I have two Visual Studios launched - one for my managed dll and one for native debugged exe. I can attach my dll to the process of the Visual Studio running native exe and set a breakpoint. When user adds variable in the Watch window, my breakpoint is hit. I can see that all parameters is passed correctly and function works fine till the return statement is reached.

After that, I have an `Unhandled exception at 0x51ea9de4 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000`.

The same works fine for unmanaged dlls. So can anyone guess where the problem hides?

Both Visual Studios are of 2010 version.

Yes, I can use unmanaged dll to accept this call and then pass control to another managed dll, but the Occam's razor principle tells me not to do that.

**Update:**
`pResult` is not a NULL, and exception is thrown even if I comment `strcpy_s` out.

Comment: Have you tried running the same using a single instance of VS? I mean, just start debugging your exe in one VS and go from there, does the AV get reproduced in this case?

Comment: @unkulunkulu In this case VS is just crashed at the moment when my dll is called to evaluate content of a variable. I can debug it after crash and see the same AV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to set `stdcall` calling convention on this function explicitly, this should help.

```
__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT __stdcall CvMatViewer(DWORD dwAddress, DEBUGHELPER *pHelper, 
    int nBase, BOOL bUniStrings, char *pResult, size_t max, DWORD reserved);
```

Comment: In this case function is not even invoked from VS. And since all the parameters seemed to look right with default `__cdecl` convention (i.e. the value of `nBase` was 10, and `max` was 2048), I don't think calling convention is an issue.

Comment: @Mikhail, the parameters will be passed correctly no matter what convention is used, these two differ only in who cleans up the stack.

Comment: @Mikhail, the reason the function is not being called now is probably the altered name mangling scheme with `__stdcall` (it happens with `extern C` only), you have to write a module definition file to export the function under unmangled name. How in the world the wrong calling convention could be not an issue?

Comment: Whoa! I was sure placing `__declspec(dllexport)` directive and providing module definition file have the same effect! But specifying .def instead of `__declspec(dllexport)` disabled mangling and `__stdcall` did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would check if pResult is actually not a null pointer before copying data in it. That is most likely you problem, given the size of the function.

Comment: No, it is not a NULL, and exception is thrown even if I comment this `strcpy_s` out.